# How can I use generics to provide a "universal getter method"?

Tags: java, generics

This question is more theoretical (what I want to do is more complicated but this is the part I'm stuck on), so apologies for the contrived example which may not make much sense.

Say I have some class that has methods that return its value in different forms:

```
public class MyObject {
    public String getAsString() {...}
    public int getAsInt() {...}
    // and so on
}
```

I'm trying to create a single method to allow me to specify which MyObject method to call via its parameters.  Something like:

```
public <T> T getValue(MyObject obj, Class<T> c) {
    if (c == String.class) {
        return obj.getAsString();
    } else if (c == Integer.class) {
        return obj.getAsInt();
    } // and so on
}
```

So then I would like to call this method like this, assuming obj is a MyObject:

```
String s = getValue(obj, String.class);
int i = getValue(obj, Integer.class);
// and so on
```

I'm getting the compile error "Type mismatch:  cannot convert from String to T" (and likewise for Integer) in the getValue method.  Clearly I'm just not understanding generics fully, but I thought this was the general idea behind generics - here I'm specifying (or trying to specify, at least) the real type of T via the parameter c.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have a try `return c.cast(obj.getAsString())`, does it work for you

Comment: What are you doing in `getAsString` and `getAsInt`? Converting values? Or are you just casting `Object`-typed values to method return types?

Comment: @ernest_k - does it matter with respect to the error I'm getting?  It's a really contrived example intended to really just focus on the generic type and the error I was getting (sorry), so let's just assume that getAsString returns "hello" and getAsInt returns 42.

Comment: @ProGu Yes!  Compiles at least.  Why?

Comment: @Jer I was about to post an answer that made the assumption that your API contract assumes the caller knows the data type of values they're getting. If you are not converting values, then all this casting can be avoided altogether. In that sense, whether you're converting or just casting matters. The `getValue()` API is rather easy to simplify.

Comment: @ernest_k well, yes - in my (real) example, the caller does know the (intended) data type, but often (in the case of bad data) that won't be true, and an exception would be thrown.  The real use case for this is that I want to call this repeatedly for multiple (say 20) different instances of MyObject, catching the exception in getValue(), and continuing on for the rest of the instances.  Without this, I'd either have a big try block wrapping all of the calls to getValue, but if any of them threw an exception, then I would stop processing the others.  Or I'd need 20 try/catch blocks.

Comment: @Jer I think the flow you're referring to (calling repeatedly, try/catch) is beside the question you posted, but I have a feeling that this is an XY problem (just having difficulties imagining that you would be specifically declaring the data type of each call to `getValue()` if you have to iterate a list of `MyObject` instances, but this is surely me not knowing enough about your concrete use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to to create a single method with really safe casts - then I would suggest to setup a mapping between the expected `type` and its respective `getter`.

Given the `MyObject` class definition as:

```
public class MyObject {

    public int getIntValue() {
        return 42;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return "Answer";
    }
}
```

So that the "accessor" class could look as follows (it can be generalized further if needed):

```
public class MyObjectAccessor {    
    private final Map<Class<?>, Function<MyObject, ?>> registry = new HashMap<>();
    
    public Accessor() {
        registerGetter(Integer.class, MyObject::getIntValue);
        registerGetter(String.class, MyObject::getStringValue);
    }
    
    private <T> void registerGetter(Class<T> type, Function<MyObject, T> getter) {
        registry.put(type, getter);
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Optional<T> getValue(MyObject obj, Class<T> type) {
        return (Optional<T>) ofNullable(registry.get(type)).map(getter -> getter.apply(obj));
    }
}
```

This would allow you to make the behavior much more predictable with a control over the unexpected/missing mapping.
(Here it returns an `Optional` back, but you can also throw an exception or provide a default value or do something else)

---

*Please note that the cast inside `getValue` is actually a safe checked cast (even though it was marked with `@SuppressWarnings`) as the "safety" proof here is a little bit beyond current javac's capability of static code analysys.*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *if* `getAsString` and `getAsInt` are not doing any conversion (such as would be the case if all your values were stored as strings), you probably can reduce your method to this:

```
public <T> T getValue(MyObject obj) {
    return (T) obj.value;
}
```

This will have an unchecked cast warning, but that's not worse than leaving the typing decision to your caller (so I'd just `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` it). If your caller uses the wrong target type, they will get a `ClassCastException` at runtime, which I assume goes well with your current contract. But you can keep `c.cast(obj.getAsX())` if you want the exception to be raised in your own method.

With the above, your callers would just use:

```
String s = getValue(obj);
int i = getValue(obj);
```

If, however, you are actually converting data in `getAs...` methods, then you will need to cast in your generic getter after dispatching to the correct getAsX method, at least as [ProGu suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69565425/how-can-i-use-generics-to-provide-a-universal-getter-method#comment122959410_69565425) (i.e., `return c.cast(obj.getAsX())` in each branch).